# L1 and L2 norms in R

Tags: r

I have a vector `e <- c(0.1, -0.1, 0.1)` and I want to calculate L1 and L2 norms. I am using `norm(e, type="2")` which works fine for L2 norm but when I change it to `norm(e, type="1")` or `norm(e, type="I")`, *R-Studio* returns following error:

```
Error in norm(e, type = "1") : 'A' must be a numeric matrix
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: Have a look at `?norm`. Maybe it will clarify

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the problem, use`e <- as.matrix(c(0.1, -0.1, 0.1))`.

right below is the body of the norm function, if `type!="2"`, it will skip to `.Internal(La_dlange(x,type))`, I guess this cause type 2 special but I can't give any further explain.

```
function (x, type = c("O", "I", "F", "M", "2")) 
{
  if (identical("2", type)) {
    svd(x, nu = 0L, nv = 0L)$d[1L]
  }
  else .Internal(La_dlange(x, type))
}
```